# "Canonical surjective map" from $\mathbb{K}$-algebra to $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb{K} M$ (module)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra for a field $\mathbb{K}$ (not algebraically closed), with $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{K} A = n^2$.

Let $M$ be an irreducible $A$-module with $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{K} M = n$. In an article I am reading, the author says "Let $$p: A \to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{K} M$$ be the canonical surjective map such that..."

How is that defined? Because if it is the map given by the representation I really can't see why it should be surjective (maybe it has to do with how $M$ is defined). I just want to know if this is a general fact or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the map given by the representation. A general condition implying that the map is surjective is that $M$ is not only irreducible but that $\text{End}_k(M) \cong k$, which is stronger than irreducibility (although follows if $M$ is finite-dimensional and $k$ is algebraically closed by Schur's lemma); this follows from the [Jacobson density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem).

The condition on dimensions does not suffice. For example, let $L$ be a finite extension of $k$, let $A = L \times L$, and let $M = L$ with the action given by the first factor. It would suffice if in addition you knew that $A$ was simple, or as above that $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Actually the aim is to prove that $A$ is simple... could you elaborate a bit on how it follows from Jacobson's density theorem?

Comment: @Analysis: take the finite linearly independent set to be a basis for $M$ as a $k$-module.